# Some adjustable chess engines below 3000 elo?

Tags: engines

Stockfish, Alphazero, Leela chess zero, Komodo have elo above 3300. I need the names of some adjustable chess engines below 3000 level, from beginner level to Grand Master level (2800 to 3000 elo), like Shredder?

Answer (score 2):

I did some [test](http://talkchess.com/forum3/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=71199) on engines that support UCI_Elo option.

Sample engines that supports said option. There are others. The list below are tested on UCI_Elo 2300.

```
   # PLAYER                              :  RATING  ERROR  POINTS  PLAYED   (%)
   1 Cheng 4.39 ucielo 2300              :  3187.9  173.9    95.0     102    93
   2 Fruit reloaded v3.21 ucielo 2300    :  2945.0  141.5    78.5     102    77
   3 Amyan 1.72 ucielo 2300              :  2832.9  134.8    68.0     103    66
   4 Cheese 2.0 ucielo 2300              :  2823.7  135.1    66.5     102    65
   5 Lc0 0.21.2 w48x5 blas               :  2789.5  119.1   154.0     243    63
   6 Rhetoric 1.4.3 ucielo 2300          :  2726.9  129.6    56.0     102    55
   7 Discocheck 5.2 ucielo 2300          :  2652.3  129.2    48.0     102    47
   8 Arasan 21.3 ucielo 2300             :  2628.2  126.3    45.5     102    45
   9 Wasp 3.60 ucielo 2300               :  2535.3  125.1    36.5     102    36
  10 CT800 V1.34 ucielo 2300             :  2300.0   ----    19.0     102    19
  11 D2019.2.37.53 ucielo 2300           :  2159.2  143.1    11.5     102    11
  12 Hiarcs 14 ucielo 2300               :  1983.5  188.0     4.5     102     4
```

The engine `D2019.2.37.53` is my engine [Deuterium](https://sites.google.com/view/deuterium-chess/download/engines/chess).

Answer (score 1):

A lot ... Pick your engine from the CCRL rating list: https://ccrl.chessdom.com/ccrl/4040.

Answer (score 0):

Lichess has a software system with 8 levels. Level 1 has a ELO rating close to 0 because it loses on purpose. Level 8 is the strongest version of Stockfish. The other 6 levels are in between. It is available on your computer, tablet or cell phone. You can download the Lichess app. Good luck in your chess journey!

Steps to play:

1. Go to https://lichess.org/
2. Select ***Play.***
3. Select ***Play with the Computer.***
4. Select the **level** that you want to use (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7 or 8).
5. Select the color that you want to play
6. Start!

[image: Lichess.org]